# How to set up an Applescript to remove attachments in Mail as part of a rule?

Tags: mail.app, applescript, attachments, mail-rules

I'm on Sierra and have MailActOn in Mail.

I want to set up an Outbox mail rule to run an Applescript that effectively will delete all email attachments on the message I am replying to, after delivery.

PS. For anyone unfamiliar with MailActOn, it allows me to run an Applescript as part of an Outbox rule. So, I suspect any Applescript that will just remove email attachments would help me achieve the above.

Thanks for any help.